# Is there a way to blend an opacity overlay in a "mix" like nature without using an FBO?

Tags: opengl

I have done this many times whilst using FBO's, but in this unique case i would prefer not to use an FBO.

I have tried a multitude of `gl.BlendFunc()` and `gl.BlendFuncSeparate()` variations and none of them comes close to the desired result. The color of the background and the overlay are the same, so basically all i want to do is to paint over the already drawn with the overlay texture.

When using `gl.BlendFunc(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)` it works as expected for the text and button, but also makes makes the background darker, which i don't want.

I am not sure whether or not this is actually possible without using an FBO. I have a few rather complicated ideas of how to fix this, but i thought i would ask here in case there is a simple `gl.BlendFunc()` combination or something equivelant.

I have two things i would like "blended" together and provide the following results:

Before overlay:
[image]

Overlay:(alpha 1 in top and alpha 0 in bottom)
[image]

The desired result:
[image]

Comment: When you say “makes the background darker”, what do you mean? In the existing images you provide, it seems like the background of “Before overlay” is fully black, so it can't be further darkened. If it's not going to be black in the final result, how do you plan to distinguish the text and button from the background?

Comment: It isn't fully black, but a bit hard to see on the small image. If you click(go big picture) it you will noticeably see it is a dark teal. Adding the overlay image makes the dark teal become even darker where it has it has an alpha value > 0.  This is to be expected from gl.BlendFunc(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the effect you want, you need to provide *the background color* as one of the inputs — on a pixel-by-pixel basis, the blend function has no idea itself what is the text and what is the background, so you need to provide the background.

Use either your fragment shader, or the overlay texture's color channels, to produce the dark background color as the color that is being blended, together with the alpha ramp you already have. Then, a `(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)` blend, the same as you'd use for any texture-with-alpha, will get the result you want.